# How to stop a docker database container

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

Trying to run the following docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres
    container_name: pg_container
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: partman
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: partman
      POSTGRES_DB: partman


  app:
    build: .
    container_name: partman_container
    links:
     - database
    environment:
     - DB_NAME=partman
     - DB_USER=partman
     - DB_PASSWORD=partman
     - DB_HOST=database
     - DB_PORT=5432
     - SECRET_KEY='=321t+92_)@%_4b+f-&0ym(fs2p5-0-_nz5mhb_cak9zlo!bv@'
    depends_on:
      - database

    expose:
      - "8000"
      - "8020"

    ports:
       - "127.0.0.1:8020:8020"

volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

when running docker-compose up-build with the following docker file

```
# Dockerfile

# FROM directive instructing base image to build upon
FROM python:3.7-buster


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx vim -y --no-install-recommends
COPY nginx.default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log


RUN mkdir .pip_cache \
 mkdir -p /opt/app \
 mkdir -p /opt/app/pip_cache \
 mkdir -p /opt/app/py-partman

COPY start-server.sh /opt/app/
COPY requirements.txt start-server.sh /opt/app/
COPY .pip_cache /opt/app/pip_cache/
COPY partman /opt/app/py-partman/

WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --cache-dir /opt/app/pip_cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /opt/app 
RUN /bin/bash -c 'ls -la; chmod +x /opt/app/start-server.sh; ls -la'

EXPOSE 8020
STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

CMD ["/opt/app/start-server.sh"]
```

/opt/app/start-server.sh :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# start-server.sh
ls
pwd

cd py-partman
ls
pwd
python manage.py createsuperuser --no-input
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py initialize_entities
```

the database image keeps on running, i want to stop it because otherwise the jenkins job will keep on waiting for the image to terminate.

Any good ideas / better ideas how to do so ?

Comment: Docker stop <id from container database>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with -> docker stop <"container id or container name">

Use -f to force it, if it can't be stopped.
Try it.

Comment: that wouldn't solve the case because we want the image to terminate as soon as it finishes building by itself

Comment: Maybe you can create a bin/setup script, and initialize it after creating the docker image, not doing CMD ["/opt/app/start-server.sh"]
on dockerfile, doing it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Compose is generally oriented around long-running server-type processes, and where database containers can frequently take 30-60 seconds to start up, it's usually beneficial to not repeat them.  (In fact, the artifacts you show look a little odd for not including a `python manage.py runserver` command.)

It looks like there is a [docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) option for what you're looking for

```
docker-compose up --build --abort-on-container-exit
```

If you wanted to do this more manually, and especially if your `app` container's normal behavior is to actually start a server, you can [docker-compose run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) the initialization command.  This will start up the container and its dependencies, but it also expects its command to return, and then you can clean up yourself.

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose run app /opt/app/initialize-only.sh
docker-compose down -v
```

Comment: the command i shared uses gunicorn to start the service, it forks worker from process, i want the image to stop after it build, but i think the database is preventing it from terminating